# Java/MongoDB - How to resolve error "exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object"

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using `aggregate()` method and looking result in cursor for that I am using below code

```
                 dbObjArray = new BasicDBObject[2]
                 dbObjArray[0]= cruxLevel
                 dbObjArray[1] = project
                // dbObjArray[2] = out
                 List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(dbObjArray)
                 if (!datasetObject?.isFlat && jsonFor != 'collection-grid') {
                     println '-------------------------------- inside if block bbb--------------------------------------'
                     output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(pipeline)
                 }else{

                     /*DBObject out = new BasicDBObject('$out':"datasetTemp");
                     def db = getDB()*/

                     println '-------------------------------- inside else block--------------------------------------'

                      AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder()
                     .batchSize(100)
                     .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR)
                     .allowDiskUse(true)
                     .build();

                     output = dataSetCollection.aggregate(project)
                 }
```

I am getting below error.

> com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" :
>   "127.0.0.1:15847" , "errmsg" : "exception: pipeline element 0 is not
>   an object" , "code" : 15942 , "ok" : 0.0}

Where I'm going wrong please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is missing some crucial elements that would be helpful with debugging, for example what are the values of the variables `cruxLevel` and `project`? What is the json equivalent representation of the pipeline?

Comment: @chridam tell me how can I help you exactly. cruxlevel and project has very complex thing.

Comment: What are the values of the variables `cruxLevel` and `project`?

Comment: @chridam Please see edit

Comment: Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def dbObjArray = new BasicDBObject[1]
dbObjArray[0]= project
List<DBObject> flatPipeline = Arrays.asList(dbObjArray)

AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder()
                                        .batchSize(100)
                                        .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR)
                                        .allowDiskUse(true)
                                        .build();
def cursor = dataSetCollection.aggregate(flatPipeline,aggregationOptions)
```